# Adding class to the last element of the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-selecter-plugin

I seem to have a problem adding a class to span tag.

This is generated dynamically when `$("select").selecter();` is called since i'm using [selecter jquery](http://formstone.it/components/selecter).

```
<div class="selecter">
    <span class="selecter-selected">...</span>
    <div class="selecter-options">
        <span class="selecter-item"></span>
        <span class="selecter-item"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

backbone.js

```
var Test = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(".container"),
    initialize: function(){
        $("select").selecter();
        this.$el.find("div.selecter-item").first().addClass("selected"); // This works
        this.$el.find("div.selecter-item").first().addClass("first"); // this works
        this.$el.find("div.selecter-item").last().addClass("last"); //Does not work
    }
});

var test = new Test();
```

Output:

```
<div class="selecter">
    <span class="selecter-selected">...</span>
    <div class="selecter-options">
        <span class="selecter-item selected first"></span>
        <span class="selecter-item"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see nothing is added to the 2nd selecter-item class. I even tried the following:

```
this.$el.find("div.selecter-item:last").addClass("last");
this.$el.find("div.selecter-item:last-child").addClass("last");
this.$el.find("div.selecter-item:nth-child(2)").addClass("last");
this.$el.find(".selecter-item:last").addClass("last");
this.$el.find(".selecter-item").last().addClass("last");
```

but still does not work. How can I add the last class to the last selecter-item class?

Comment: Probably because selecter-item is not the div element but span? Try to change to span.selecter-item

Comment: `this.$el.find(".selecter-item:last").addClass("last");`

Comment: @Pavlo, Still the same even if i change it to span

Comment: as @Pavlo said your selector `div.selecter-item` does not match any element as the `.selecter-item` elements are `span`s.

Comment: @ArunPJohny, still does not work. I already tried that.

Comment: By the way, you can write `this.$('css selector')` instead of `this.$el.find('css selector')`.

Comment: can you try to log the value of `this.$el.find("div.selecter-item").length` before adding the class in `initialize` method

Comment: Close quotes for those two spans at the end of class: <span class="selecter-item selected first></span>
<span class="selecter-item></span>

Comment: @Pavlo, sorry about that that's just mistype. It's not really adding a class to the last element of span. I've updated my post.

Comment: can you check this and let me know if it works for you? http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/S2gc8/  Note: without using backbone

Comment: @Pavlo, do you think $("select").selecter(); has not yet completed adding elements? that's why when i add class the element does not exist yet?

Comment: @Pavlo, yes it works since the div and span tags are hard coded and not generated dynamically.

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Well it can't find anything since $("select").selecter(); is not yet initialized.

Comment: @Defyleiti, Could you please create jsfiddle with your exact problem?

Comment: @Defyleiti you can update this one http://jsfiddle.net/26Kcq/ with your problem

Comment: @RidaBENHAMMANE, ok sure

Comment: @RidaBENHAMMANE, I don't know what's wrong but it works in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/26Kcq/1/ What version of selecter did you use?

Comment: Selecter v3.0.8 - 2014-02-10

Comment: Is `selector` a child of `.container`? If it is not, `this.$el.find()` won't find it. Side note you can just use `this.$('')` to select elements within your view.